# No public execute() in class mydomain error

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, reverse-engineering, nant-task

I want to use `Hibernate Tools` for reverse engineering.

My database is `PostgreSQL`. Problem is about `hbm.xml` file. Reverse engineering tool creating wrong `hbm.xml` files. So, I want to use `custom reverse engineering strategy.` I am using `Java.`

`CustomReverseEngineeringStrategy` class is here:

```
    public class CustomReverseEngineeringStrategy extends DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy{

        public CustomReverseEngineeringStrategy(ReverseEngineeringStrategy delegate) {
            super(delegate);
        }

        public CustomReverseEngineeringStrategy(){
            super(new CustomReverseEngineeringStrategy());
        }


        public Properties getTableIdentifierProperties(TableIdentifier arg0) {
              Properties pr = new Properties();
              pr.put("sequence", "test_id_seq");
              return pr;
        }

        public String getTableIdentifierStrategyName(TableIdentifier arg0) {
              return "sequence";
        }


}
```

[Edit]

I Wrote `Ant` taskdef and I have an error.

Here is my `build.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- define the project -->

<project name="sample_BookCatalog" default="build" basedir=".">


    <!-- define project properties -->
    <property name="compiler" value="modern" />
    <property name="fork" value="no" />
    <property name="verbose" value="no" />
    <property name="debug" value="on" />
    <property name="optimize" value="on" />
    <property name="deprecation" value="on" />
    <property name="target" value="1.5" />
    <property name="source" value="1.5" />
    <property file="build.properties" />
    <property environment="env" />

    <!-- define properties to refer to directories in the project -->
    <property name="webinf.dir" value="WEB-INF" />
    <property name="webinf.lib.dir" value="WEB-INF/lib" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="test.dir" value="test" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="build" />
    <property name="webinf.classes.dir" value="${webinf.dir}/classes" />
    <property name="webinf.classes.content.dir" value="${webinf.dir}/classes/content" />

    <property name="web.xml" value="${webinf.dir}/web.xml" />


    <fileset id="webapp.libs" dir="${webinf.lib.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>

    <fileset id="libs" dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>

    <path id="class.path">
        <pathelement path="${webinf.classes.dir}" />
        <fileset refid="webapp.libs" />
        <fileset dir = "${webinf.lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        <fileset refid="libs" />
    </path>

    <pathconvert pathsep=":" property="class.path" refid="class.path" />

    <fileset id="war.files" dir=".">
        <include name="${webinf.dir}/**" />
        <exclude name="${webinf.dir}/Language-ext.properties" />
        <include name="images/**" />
        <include name="css/**" />
        <include name="js/**" />
        <exclude name="${web.xml}" />
    </fileset>

    <!-- compile target to compile the sources -->
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${webinf.classes.dir}" />
        <!-- Content directory contains Liferay resource bundle-->

        <mkdir dir="${webinf.classes.content.dir}" />
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}:${test.dir}" destdir="${webinf.classes.dir}" fork="${fork}" verbose="${verbose}" deprecation="${deprecation}" debug="${debug}" optimize="${optimize}" compiler="${compiler}" target="${target}" source="${source}">
            <classpath refid="class.path" />
        </javac>
        <copy todir="${webinf.classes.dir}" preservelastmodified="true">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.properties" />
                <include name="**/*.xml" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${webinf.classes.content.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${webinf.dir}">
                <include name="Language-ext.properties" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>


    </target>

    <!-- <taskdef name="mytask" classname="com.project.strategy.Reverse"/> -->



    <property name="my.classes" value="${webinf.classes.dir}" />
    <taskdef name="mytask" classpath="${my.classes}" classname="com.project.strategy.Reverse"/>


    <!-- target to create the project WAR file -->
    <target name="build" depends="clean,compile">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <war destfile="${build.dir}/sample_BookCatalog.war" webxml="${web.xml}">
            <fileset refid="war.files" />
        </war>
        <copy todir="${liferay.portal.home}/deploy">
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.war" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <!-- target to clean up all files created by various tasks -->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete quiet="true" includeemptydirs="true">
            <fileset dir="${webinf.classes.dir}" includes="**/*" />
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}" />
            <fileset dir="${work.dir}" />
        </delete>
    </target>
</project>
```

Here is error :

```
No public execute() in class com.project.strategy.Reverse
```

Regards

Comment: Tag your programming language !

Comment: If you wish a tool to create mapping and other xml files automatically then the best one to use is NetBeans IDE.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i cant chance now my IDE. So, i must solve this problem in Eclipse.